# exclude sub directory from www redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an .htaccess in my root directory to redirect www domain to non-www domain so that http://www.example.com/ goes to http://example.com/

i need to exclude /admin folder that has .htaccess password protection and seems to cause same trouble with non www redirection

the code that i used to ignore the admin directory in root folder is the following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

when i test this i end up on 401 error page

inside /admin folder .htaccess has

```
<Files ~ "^.(htaccess|htpassword|htgroup)$">
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine Off

AuthUserFile /myserver/.htpassword
AuthGroupFile /myserver/.htgroup

AuthName "Reserved Area"
AuthType Basic

require valid-user
order deny,allow

ErrorDocument 401 /myserver/errore.html
ErrorDocument 404 /myserver/notfound.html
```

Comment: Since you already have a .htaccess in `/admin/` folder therefore your `www` removal rule won't affect `http://www.example.com/admin/` URL.

Comment: any way to do  remove www. from website url except for /admin folder?

Comment: Your `www` removal is already doing it. It won't impact `/admin/`. Test in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled and make sure Apache config doesn't have `www` removal rule.